# How can I arrange the Fields in 4 equal columns inside a grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I have a UI and I want to arrange them in 4 equal columns with label and input field coming in the same line inside the grid or form.
I actually want to know the class to apply for div tag containing a pair of label and input field.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap or something similar or just coding everything yourself?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Bootstrap 4 Grid System**

Sample:

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
      <div class="col-3" style="background-color:Orange;">25%</div>
      <div class="col-3" style="background-color:DarkOrange;">25%</div>
      <div class="col-3" style="background-color:Green;">25%</div>
      <div class="col-3" style="background-color:DarkGreen;">25%</div>
    </div>
```

read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)